# What do you call the property of a shape that looks the same for some rotations?

Tags: symmetry, spheres

Specifically I mean a fragment of a sphere(e.g. for $x,y,z > 0$). It looks the same if you look at this from $(1,0,0)$ or $(0,1,0)$ or $(0,0,1)$. What do you call the property? I thought it would be some kind of symmetry but it seems symmetry is not a good name for it.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotational_symmetry) might be relevant to you.

Comment: It seems this article answers my question, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1408546/what-do-you-call-the-property-of-a-shape-that-looks-the-same-for-some-rotations?noredirect=1#comment2869318_1408546) has been given by [Stefan](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/217623/stefan). The property is called *rotational symmetry*.